# SAS MLE estimation for a vector of parameters

Tags: loops, sas

```
proc iml;
use rdata2;
read all var _all_ into xy;
close rdata2;
print xy;

use ppfinal2;
read all var _all_ into ppxy;
close ppfinal2;
print ppxy;

start f_prob(beta) global(xy, ppxy);
p = nrow(xy);
sum1 = 0.; sum2 = 0.;
do i = 1 to p;
    sum1 = sum1 + xy*beta;
    suminside&i. = 0.;
    n = nrow(ppxy(SOME CONDITIONED ROWS));
    do j = 1 to n;
        suminside&i. = suminside&i. + ppxy(SOME CONDITIONED ROWS)*beta;
    end;
    sum2 = sum2 + log(suminside&i.);
end;
f = sum1 - sum2;
return(f);
finish f_prob;
```

I am intending to do a mle estimation of beta, which is a vector of 10 unknown parameters. xy contains all the observations in a matrix form, with 10 columns per observation.

There is another larger matrix ppxy with 10 columns as well but i just want to specify some rows of ppxy in the inner do loop for every iteration.

Is there any way i can condition ppxy to get the first 12 rows of ppxy when i = 1, and the next 12 rows of ppxy for i = 2 .... and so on. Also, can this way be used for mle estimation for a vector of beta parameters? Or are there other ways? I am using SAS UE. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For an overview and example of MLE estimation in SAS/IML, see ["Maximum likelihood estimation in SAS/IML'](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/10/12/maximum-likelihood-estimation-in-sasiml.html)

For your specific question, use the following code to obtain submatrices of the big ppxy matrix:

```
do i = 1 to p;
    LastRow = 12*i;           /* 12, 24, 36, etc */
    FirstRow = LastRow - 11;  /*  1, 13, 25, etc */
    ppxy_i = ppxy[FirstRow:LastRow, ];
    /* use ppxy_i in computations */
end;
```

The matrix `ppxy_i` changes during each iteration. It contains 12 rows of the `ppxy` matrix, where the rows change by multiples of 12 during the iteration.